# Combine data through SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

[My query is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW8ni.png)

Dear All,

I am trying to retrieve data from two tables and the result need as on attached format.

Please help.

Thanks.
Titus

Comment: Please read (and understand) [ask] in [help].

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query

```
    select a.Group as Group, b.Name as Debit, bb.Name as Credit  From A a
    Join B b on a.DebitId=b.Id
    join B bb on a.CreditId=bb.Id
```

you will get the required result .